# visual studio debug on different system

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, remote-debugging

I want to write/debug my code in visual studio 2010 in my laptop. 
Once I am done i want it to run on my desktop visual studio in debug mode.
Currently I copy the code using RDP.How do I do this more efficiently?

I can not afford to buy Team foundation. I was hoping there is a svn service.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say one solution yourself - use svn, or other version control.

Another alternative is folder sharing. If you wish to work with the laptop offline as well, I recommend svn or git.

As a programmer, you must use version control. It's your friend!

Comment: Thanks. I don't like the svn idea cause it is still an offline process. Can anyone tell me about Remote Debugger in visual studio? can it be used over internet?

Comment: It seems it can. I faced some articles on that recently, when looking for DEBUGMSG over ActiveSync/WMDC connection. Let's see... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/117401/activesync-4-0-lacks-ethernet-connectivity "CMAccept.exe" seems to be the key to what you want. But.. that might only apply to Windows CE development. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you want to achieve.  If you just want to debug on the desktop machine, sharing a folder is the most efficient way as it doesn't involve lots of copying and risking files being out of date, though it may be slow if your application requires a lot of file accesses.  If the application has a lot of data files then an alternative could be to mount a shared drive on the desktop machine but use robocopy to keep the directories in sync:

```
robocopy /mir \\laptop\source\myproject c:\desktopmachine\myproject
```

You can also do [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from the laptop which is very powerful.

If you want the test (as opposed to debug) the application, then a more robust approach is to create a release build (and installer, if appropriate) on the laptop and then copy that across to your desktop.  As akauppi says, you should definitely be using SVN or another version control system for source control, but I think that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking into remote debugging. I couldnt figure out how to do it over the internet. Can you help me with that?
Also, are there any free svn service that keep the repository private? thanks.

Comment: I just asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458454/remote-debugger-over-internet

Comment: If the machines are both on the same domain then that makes remote debugging much easier and you can probably use the Default transport (the qualifier is then just the name or IP of the remote machine).  Since you can connect to the machine via a static IP you can also use the 'Remote' transport, but bear in mind that this may be unsafe over the internet.  If you are connected via a VPN then this might not be a problem.

Comment: As for the SVN question, it depends on your needs.  If you are the only person using it then setting it up on a host server you have access to may be the easiest.  There are certainly commercial SVN providers out there but I don't know of any free ones that are also private.